# How do I properly use a for loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, project

I'm trying to improve my Ruby skills using the Project Euler series of questions and I'm wondering why this code does not work for this question: "Even Fibonacci numbers, Problem 2"

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
```

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My code:

```
def fibo(n)
  first, second, sequence = 0,1,[]
  for e in n
    first, second = second, first + second
    sequence << e if e%2 == 0
  end
  sequence.inject(:+)
end

puts fibo(4000000)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In the line:

```
for e in n
```

4,000,000 is being substituted for n, so you are saying:

```
for e in 4000000
```

which is not a valid statement - you cannot iterate on an integer.

If you would like to iterate through all the values from 0 to n, try:

```
for e in (0..n)
```

This iterates through the values in the **range** 0 to n.

However, there is a deeper problem here. It looks as though you want to iterate up to the value 4000000, but instead your code would iterate through the first 4000000 Fibonacci numbers, which is much more than you want. You may want to consider saying:

```
while second <= 4000000
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) if you're starting out with Ruby. It's a fun way of getting used to the ways of the language.

That said your code is not calculating Fibonacci correctly, it's not summing the Fibonacci numbers and also has some other errors (`for e in n` is not valid because `n` is not an Enumerator type). Fix it like this:

```
def fibo(n)
  first, second, sum = 0, 1, 0
  loop do
    first, second = second, first + second
    sum += second if second%2 == 0
    break if second >= n
  end
  sum
end
```